How to run shell script when opening trace32 window?
I need to run on shell script when I am opening trace32 window.
So I have added:
./gen_cmm.sh file.h
in
config.t32
file last line.
But it is not called when I am opening trace32 window.
What I need to do?
My knowledge is config.t32 is called when I am just open trace32 window.
I am expecting to generate
output.cmm
file as a output file.
I need the output in my desired location, not where config.t32 is present.

To run a shell script (like gen_cmm.sh) from TRACE32 PowerView, you need to use the TRACE32 command OS.Command <commandline>.
To get OS.Command executed automatically after the start of TRACE32 PowerView add it to a PRACTICE script (aka. cmm-script) and add the path to that script to the TRACE32 command line with parameter -s.
E.g.:

You have the shell script /tmp/gen_cmm.sh. Please use an absolute path to your shell script.
Create a text-file containing the line OS.Command /tmp/gen_cmm.sh and save it at /tmp/myLaunch.cmm(or wherever you like).
To the execution path of the TRACE32 binary (e.g. /opt/t32/t32marm) add the script with -s like this: /opt/t32/t32marm -s /tmp/myLaunch.cmm

